# django + celery + redis + postgres is hang

Tags: django, azure, celery, gevent, eventlet

I am deploying my project into ms azure linux vm.

each service is deployed in different server. actually for servers.

But, It's not working.

celeryd is always hang with over the 20~30 http request.

And then it is work after ctrl+c and restart celeryd.
but.. it also hang soon.

Eventlet and gevent are also use.. but.. eventlet is not working well.. gevent is better..

I think postgres or usage of model is one of problem. but.. I don't know exactly why..

Anybody help me out?!!!

Is it correct usage of django model below?

> sync_service_log = SyncServiceLog.objects.get(pk = sync_log["service"])
>       sync_service_log.save()
>   
> .
> .
> {{some codes}}
> .
> .
>   sync_service_log.save()

Answer (score 0):

The information provided is not enough to pin point the exact root cause. Are you installing all of these modules on a one Linux VM? 
The best option is to build a a Linux VM first locally with all the necessary modules in it and the deploy to Windows Azure and configure all necessary Ports to connect with it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you apply eventlet/gevent monkey patches at all? You should do that in order to make psycopg (postgres driver) async. It'll always block without the monkey patch.